# Why don't these /execute parameters check for the entity in the specified position?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a system set up to trigger a command block if an entity walks to that spot. However, it is setting off the trigger without an entity being there. This is the command that I'm using:

```
execute if entity @e positioned -86 5 82 run fill -88 4 79 -88 4 79 minecraft:redstone_block
```

Why is my command running even when an entity is not in that location?

Comment: `/execute positioned` does nothing if you don't use the coordinates for anything and `/execute if entity @e` is pretty much always true.

Answer (score 1):

Your command is testing for an entity with the selector `@e`, which is *any* entity. This will almost always be true while you are on the world / server.

The `positioned` means that the command is ran from the location, so if you did `/execute positioned x y z run setblock ^ ^ ^ stone` then the block at x y z would be set to stone.

The correct version of this command would be:

```
/execute positioned x y z if entity @e[distance=..1] run fill xyz1 xyz2 block
```

And obviously you would replace x y z, xyz1, xyz2 and block with your own data.

Comment: That's actually wrong: you should instead omit the `positioned` subcommand and instead use the `x`, `y`, and `z` target selector arguments.